# python import as a variable name

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I wanted to use import with a variable name. For example I wanted to do something like this

```
from var import my_class
```

I went through pythons [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module), but seems thats a little confusing. Also I seen some other posting on stack overflow that give the example of something like this

```
import importlib
my_module = importlib.import_module("var, my_class)
```

This second example does work to a certain extent. The only issue I see here var is imported but I don't see the attributes of my_class in python's namespace. How would I equate this to my original example of

```
from var import my_class
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to use `importlib` (there is no need for the second parameter):

```
var = importlib.import_module("var")

# Now, you can use the content of the module:
var.my_class()
```

There is no direct programmable equivalent for `from var import my_class`.

Comment: Couldn't you say that `my_class = importlib.import_module("var").__getattribute__("my_class")` is a direct programmable equivalent for `from var import my_class`?

Comment: @ChristopherShroba I guess you could.

Comment: how to import a module in a folder? E.g. `import modules.var`

Answer (score -2):

**Note**: As @DYZ points out in the comments, this way of solving this is not recommended in favor of importlib.  Leaving it here for the sake of another working solution, but the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) advise "Direct use of **import**() is also discouraged in favor of importlib.import_module()."

Do you mean that you want to import a module whose name is defined by a variable? If so, you can use the `__import__` method.  For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/christophershroba'
>>>
>>> name_to_import = "os"
>>> variable_module = __import__(name_to_import)
>>> variable_module.getcwd()
'/Users/christophershroba'
```

If you also want to call a variable method of that variable module you could use the `__getattribute__` method on the module to get the function, and then call it with `()` as normal.  The line below marked "See note" is not necessary, I just include it to show that the `__getattribute__` method is returning a function.

```
>>> name_to_import = "os"
>>> method_to_call = "getcwd"
>>> variable_module = __import__(name_to_import)
>>> variable_module.__getattribute__(method_to_call) # See note
<built-in function getcwd>
>>> variable_module.__getattribute__(method_to_call)()
'/Users/christophershroba'
```

More documentation available for [Python 3 here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) or [Python2 here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#__import__: This is an advanced function that is not needed in everyday Python programming, unlike `importlib.import_module()`.

Comment: The python 3 docs pretty much tell you "Note Programmatic importing of modules should use import_module() instead of this function." and the question is tagged python 3.

Comment: Oh wow.  Thank you for that! I never realized it was discouraged.  Added a note to my answer noting that!